# How to parse an Odata filter string in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, odata, azure-table-storage

I am trying to perform table operation in Azure table storage to retrieve entities based on the filters provided. I allow users to enter the filters in a text box.

I am in need to parse the filter string before sending them to Azure. How can i do it? Is there a predefined methods or package that can perform parsing this filter string? Or i have to manually write regex to perform this parsing?

Here's my Table operation done without any parsing done earlier.

```
var myFilterString = "PartitionKey eq '2' and ((PartitionKey eq '1' and RowKey eq '100') or RowKey eq '3')";
var entities = cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmented(new TableQuery().Where(myFilterString)).ToList();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean parse? Want to check the validity of it?

Comment: Yes @AthanasiosKataras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't such a way. It's all about the way it's designed.

- The queries generate api calls over http. That means that the library is not aware if your schema. It can't know your partition keys and whether they are right or not
- Check the following example

```
var query = new TableQuery<SymmetricKey>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "SymmetricKey"));
```

The library is clearly here to simplify the creation of the http call and nothing more.

- it's always a bad idea to delegate the creation of the query to your users.

It's almost never happening as you can't control what the user will do. Instead, create a list of options with some html and create the comparisons based in the input from your user, not the free text input option.

Comment: I agree with your point. But Its not necessary to validate the property Key names or the schema. The point here is just to check if this is a valid filter that can be sent to any table. The use of Key and value pairs with correct odata operators, paranthesis used are correct, and so on. Is there a way?

Comment: No, the api does not provide something like this unfortunately. I agree it would be useful but there's not.

Comment: The whole idea I think, is to use the built in functions (generate and combine) to make sure your query is correct by building it correctly.